# Thymeleaf and Springboot th:field Null

Tags: java, html, jpa, thymeleaf

I got a MVC web page and i try to get a value from a input **type="datetime-local"** and save the value in **th:field.** to be able to save these dates and also work with them

But it seams to work only in **input="text"** tags, not  type="datetime-local" because when i debug, the date value of the input that is **type="datetime-local"**

I need the client to select the Date the event its goint to start

Here is an example of the whole form and the two inputs that save the date.

Client view
[enter image description here][1]

View

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mt-5">
            <form th:action="@{/guardar/} + ${usuario.id_user}" method="post" th:object="${event}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" >Titulo </label>
                    <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Titulo" class="form-control" th:field="*{title}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="e_description" >Descripción</label>
                    <input type='text' name="e_description" th:field="*{e_description}"  placeholder="Descripcion" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="startDate">Inicio de Evento:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="time" placeholder="Inicio de Evento" class="form-control" th:field="*{startDate}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="endDate">Termino de Evento:</label>
                    <div class="input-group date" id="endDate">
                        <input type="datetime-local" id="time2"  placeholder="Termino de Evento" class="form-control" th:field="*{endDate}"/>
                        <div class="input-group-addon input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="className" >ClassName</label>
                    <input type="text" name="className" th:field="*{className}" placeholder="className" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="icon">Icono</label>
                    <input type="text" name="icon" th:field="*{icon}" placeholder="icon" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="allDay">¿Todo el día?</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="allDay" th:field="*{allDay}" />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Controller of /guardar/} + ${usuario.id_user}
@PostMapping("/guardar/{id}")

```
    public String guardar(@Valid Event event, Errors errores,@PathVariable int id,Model model) throws ParseException {
       /* if (errores.hasErrors()) {
            return "agregar";
        }*/
        UserPlanD userPlanD = userService.encontrarUsuarioPorId(id);
        model.addAttribute("usuario",userPlanD);
        event.setUser(userPlanD);
       Date inicio_evento = formatter.parse(event.getStartDate().toString());
       String termino_evento = event.getStartDate().toString();
        event.setStartDate(inicio_evento);
        List<Event> eventicos = Arrays.asList(event);
        System.out.println("Evento" + event + "y usuario: " + userPlanD);
        eventService.guardar(event);
        /*userPlanD.setEvents(eventicos);
        userService.guardar(userPlanD);*/

        return "redirect:/eventos";
    }
```

The Model is the next one:

````
@Table(name="event_calendar")
public class Event implements Serializable {

 //private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "id_event")
   private Long id_event;


   @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @NotEmpty
   private String e_description;

    @NotEmpty
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    private Date startDate;

    @NotEmpty
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
     private Date endDate;

    @NotEmpty

    private String className;

    @NotEmpty
    private String icon;

    @NotEmpty
    private String allDay;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user")
    private UserPlanD user; ```



Here its a debug result of the controller result in the line the got the next code  "System.out.println("Evento" + event + "y usuario: " + userPlanD)"





  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOYfW.png
````

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What exactly are you getting now and what do you want to happen?

Comment: I get the value from the input = null.  And I need to get the date and time value selected in the frontend for the client.